# From my purse ETH was sent a transaction that I did not send

Tags: transactions, blockchain

What should I do? I sent a transaction from my ETH wallet that I did not send. Help me please

Comment: I see that you're a new user. Welcome. I think you would get a much better response to your questions in the future if you were to add more detail. Given the above, it would be nearly impossible for anyone to actually help you as opposed to make general comments. Having said that, be careful to secure your private (and in some situations public) key to open scrutiny.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has sent ETH from your wallet, they have access to your wallet and you should try to secure remaining funds by transferring them to a new wallet.

Also all your funds are gone. Try to figure out how someone might have gotten access to your wallet.